# SQL 2008 CALs - how are they enforced?

Tags: sql-server

I am running a server that needs a very limited number of user connections (max of 5 at a time). So the 5-CAL edition of SQL 2008 Workgroup seems perfect for me. Now, what I need to know is the following: do I actually need to physically install a CAL on each machine/user that will be using the server (by using I mean reading and writing) or does the 5-CAL licence simply mean that only 5 machines/users will be able to log at any one time?

I.e. can 6 or 7 different people use this as long as only 5 of them are connecting simultaneously?

Thanks
Karl

Answer (score 4):

It's all here: [SQL Server 2008 Licensing Frequently Asked Questions](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/licensing-faq.aspx)

However, it is not the easiest to follow.

Basically, a CAL is per user or device. The difference is under "What is the difference between device client access licenses (CALs) and user CALs?" is the link above".

Whatever CAL type you use, it does not matter if only 5 can connect at once. Or one client has 200 connections open.

It is per user or per PC (User CAL or Device CAL), not per connection. In the olden days (SQL 7?) you did have per connection but it has been some time since I looked at this.

Edit, to actually answer: they are not strictly enforced in that the SQL Server instance counts things, but you'll be using the software illegally.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what licensing model you go for:

1. Per CPU licensing - no CALs required, but you pay up front for unlimited user and device access.  You are limited to the number of physical CPUs (not cores) you can have in the SQL Server box.
2. Per device CAL - you can assign a CAL to a physical device, and anyone accessing the SQL Server from that device is licensed.  So 10 people accessing the SQL Server from 1 shared computer requires you to have 1 device CAL.
3. Per user CAL - you can assign a CAL to a person, and anyone accessing the SQL Server is required to have a license.  So 10 people accessing the SQL Server from 1 shared computer requires you to have 10 user CALs, but 1 person accessing the SQL Server from 10 computers only requires you to have 1 CAL.

CALs are handled logically - there is no hard limit, just don't exceed the number of licenses you have.

http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/pricing-licensing-faq.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/licensing-faq.aspx